# Carry over influence between Breakdown levels

Tags: state-of-decay, state-of-decay-breakdown

I've recently started playing State of Decay breakdown again since it seems less boring now that vehicles can be used to store materials.

When you travel in the RV to increase the level difficulty I know that you take over your entire storage chest, plus some materials for the next base.   Do you also carry over your influence or would it be best to spend that on artillery markers prior to moving on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Influence does not carry over. However, the items that the survivors are carrying and the items in the locker will remain.

A tactic would be to buy as many expensive items as you can afford and carry before leaving in the RV and starting a new breakdown level. You can then sell those items back to the locker to get influence after you start a new breakdown level.

Comment: +1, I always do this. You lose some of your influence due to taking items using more influence than you gain, but it's minimal. You can also have all the survivors not coming with put their gear back in the stash, increasing your influence before taking the big items.